# Preview word/excel/powerpoint files in Sharepoint library for 2016 on prem

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016

I have SharePoint 2016 (on prem) and in the document library, I'd like to hover my mouse over a document and have a preview/popup like in search results.  Is it possible to create something like that in a normal library and how do I do this?  Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to view or preview Office documents in the browser for on-premises SharePoint 2016 or SharePoint 2019, you have to have [Office Online Server (OOS)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/office-online-server) installed on a separate server from your SharePoint farm (this product was formerly known as Office Web Apps).

Because this is a separate Microsoft server product, you must first follow the guidance to [Deploy Office Online Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/deploy-office-online-server), then you can follow the [SharePoint 2016 specific integration steps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/configure-office-online-server-for-sharepoint-server-2016/configure-office-online-server-for-sharepoint-server-2016).

Comment: Thank you Willman, I'll propose that to the client